# CypressJS automated CrossBrowserTesting

Tags: javascript, cypress

I've installed cypress framework on my project.

I already have multiple viewports tests running successively on my app.

Is it possible to automate cross browser testing, so I don't have to select a browser extension to run my test on?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/cross-browser-testing.html#Running-Specific-Tests-by-Browser

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In this case, there can be scenarios that you can run concurrently and there can be scenarios you need to run sequentially. I'll add the solution which I found for both problems.

For this, we need the package.json file. ( If you don't have it do an npm init ) and it will guide you through making the pachage.json

Then let's say we have two test files 1 can be run concurrently, and the other one should not be executed concurrently. let's name them as  **concurrently.js** and **sequentially.js**

To run the tests sequentially ad your cypress command inside the scripts JSON object.
Ex:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cy:sequence:chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome --spec **/sequentially.js",
    "cy:sequence:firefox": "cypress run --browser firefox --spec **/sequentially.js",
  }
```

Now you just need to run npm run command to sequence execution, in this case, it will be

> npm run cy:sequence:chrome && npm run cy:sequence:firefox

Then if you need concurrent execution, we need to add an npm package [concurently][1]

You can install it with **npm i concurrently**
Now like we did before we need to add the concurrently.js execution commands to scripts. Here we are using the concurrently package notations to add it. ( check the above URL )

so our final scripts package looks like,

```
  "scripts": {
    "cy.concurent:run" : "concurrently \"cypress run --browser chrome --spec **/concurrently.js\" \"cypress run --browser firefox --spec **/concurrently.js\"",
    "cy:sequence:chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome --spec **/sequentially.js",
    "cy:sequence:firefox": "cypress run --browser firefox --spec **/sequentially.js",
  }
```

if the above addition is not clear, we need to add the commands as quotes with **concurrently** word being the first word. it should be like

"concurrently "command1" "command2" "

Now if you need to run the tests concurrently in multiple browsers, you just need to run

> npm run cy.concurent:run

My only doubt is about the reporting, you might need to add an additional config to save browser-specific videos and reports. If not it might save the data of last execution.

Hope this helps,
Cheers.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: If npm run cy:sequence:chrome && npm run cy:sequence:firefox does not work, replace && with &